# How can I filter get-mguse based on a variable coming from a file?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

How can I filter based on a variable coming from a file:
foreach ($own in import-csv -path c:\Users\580616\DistinctOwners.csv) {(get-mguser -consistencylevel eventual -filter (displayname eq "$own.owner"))} ?

This way I get: "the term 'displayname' is not recognized ..."

foreach ($own in import-csv -path c:\Users\580616\DistinctOwners.csv) {(get-mguser -consistencylevel eventual -filter "(displayname eq $own.owner)")} ?

This way I get, "Invalid filter clause"

I expect to get a list of users.

But this one works fine, it just doesn't get the user details:
foreach ($own in import-csv -path c:\Users\580616\DistinctOwners.csv) {(echo "$own.owner")}

Comment: `-filter "displayname eq '$($own.owner)'"` is how your filter should look

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).